# MySQL: Average rating per item, using latest rating for user

Tags: mysql, average, greatest-n-per-group

I have the `items_ratings` table as follows:

```
items_ratings
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------------------+
| id | rating | user_id | item_id | created (DATETIME)  |
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------------------+
| 1  | 20     | 1       | 12      | 2017-07-12 14:00:04 |
| 2  | 80     | 2       | 12      | 2017-07-12 15:32:12 |
| 3  | 50     | 1       | 15      | 2017-08-01 11:14:04 |
| 4  | 90     | 1       | 12      | 2017-08-02 19:23:19 |
| 5  | 60     | 2       | 15      | 2017-08-05 19:23:19 |
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

I need to retrieve the average value per `item_id`, using each user's most recent rating.

The following gives me the average rating for each item:

```
SELECT AVG(rating) FROM items_ratings
GROUP BY item_id
```

I have also identified that the following query gives me the most recent row for each `user_id`, by `item_id`.

```
SELECT MAX(created), user_id, item_id FROM items_ratings
GROUP BY user_id, item_id;
```

I am unsure of how I should combine these queries to yield my desired result.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a select from join table with max created  by user_id

```
  select item_id, avg( rating) from (
      select * from items_ratings  a 
      inner join (
      SELECT MAX(created) t_created, user_id
      FROM items_ratings
      GROUP BY user_id
        ) t on  t.user_id = a.user_id and t.t_created = a.created 
      ) t1
  group by item_id
```

The inner select get the max created  by user_id, the other get all the rows that macht  and the outer  buil the avg on this group by item_id

and with the your new condition on item_id  you could use

```
   select item_id, avg( rating) from (
      select * from items_ratings  a 
      inner join (
      SELECT MAX(created) t_created, user_id, item_id
      FROM items_ratings
      GROUP BY user_id, item_id
        ) t on  t.user_id = a.user_id and  t.t_created = a.created  and  t.item_id = a.item_id
      ) t1
  group by item_id
```

Comment: Too much buil goes on around here in my opinion.

Comment: Hm... when I run this, I seem to get correct values, although an unreliable result. Sometimes it gives me one `item_id`, sometimes more.

Comment: if the condition don't change  ..  should return ever the same values .. what do you mean with"Sometimes it gives me one item_id, sometimes more."   ?...

Comment: As more data is entered into the table for the same `item_id` and for others, this query yields vastly different results (omitting `item_id`'s with values in the table)

Comment: Yes, however it omits `item_id`'s when there is a calculable average for the item. I want the query to yield averages for all `item_id`'s with a rating in the table.

Comment: what do you mean wth  "it omits item_id'" .. the query select item_id  ,, and and the inner select  is a select * ...  this mean that the inner query countain all the columns values for the filtered  rows ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151902/discussion-between-hugo-pakula-and-scaisedge).